# Showing that a posterior is Normal given improper prior

Tags: self-study, prior, posterior, hierarchical-bayesian, improper-prior

I am having difficulty showing the following problem and I suspect it has something to do with my lack of understanding of the question. The question is this:

> Suppose we have an improper prior distribution with $f_\Theta(\theta) = 1 $ for all $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ and the likelihood distribution $X | \Theta = \theta \sim N(\theta, 1)$. Show that the posterior is Normal.

I understand that the posterior distribution is proportional to the product of the prior and likelihood, but since the question did not specify, I am not sure how to interpret the likelihood distribution. In other words, I don't know if I should assume that I have 1 sample coming from that likelihood, or $n$ $iid$ samples. If $n=1$, then the question is easy enough, but otherwise I am having trouble showing that the posterior is normal.

My attempt so far is the following:
$$ 
f_\Theta(\theta|x) \propto f_\Theta(\theta) \cdot L(X=x_1, \ldots, x_n|\Theta = \theta)
$$

$$
\propto 1 \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n
f(x_i|\Theta = \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \big(-\frac{1}{2}(x_i - \theta)^2\big)
$$
$$
\propto \exp \big(-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n \big(x_i-\theta\big)^2\big)
$$

And this is where I get stuck trying to show that it is normal. Any suggestion or correction to my understanding of the problem is appreciated.

Comment: You need to expand the square and the sum and then push some stuff that doesnt depend on $\theta$ into the normalising constant/$\propto$ sign. Then you might have to complete the square on the resulting formula and you will get something that looks like a normal up to proportionality

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag.

Comment: The term "likelihood distribution" is terrible and prone to confuse any student exposed to it!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The number $n$ of observations actually matters very little in the sense that, when observing$$(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\sim\mathcal N(\theta,1)$$it is equivalent to observing a single Normal$$\bar{X}_n\sim\mathcal N(\theta,1/n)$$since the sample average is *sufficient*. If this is unclear, think *factorisation theorem*.